# Python 2D Array/List Assignment Gives Unwanted Result

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, syntax, variable-assignment

Say, I have a 2-dimensional list/array that contains 50 subarrays that look like `[0, 0]`. I want to change only some parts of the array, say the first elements of each subarray from index 15 to 29. I used a for loop to do this.

```
array = [[0,0]] * 50
for i in range(15, 30):
    array[i][0] = 1
```

But when I `print(array)`, it seems like the program changes all the first elements of each subarray. Output:

```
[[1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0]]
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong, as the logic seems sound. Can anyone identify my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array = [[0,0]] * 50` By this, your array will have `[0,0]` 50 times referencing to same [0,0]. So modifying one will modify all of them.
Instead try this: `array = [[0, 0] for _ in range(50)]`.